# Display the method annotations available in a java class using Java reflection

Tags: java, methods, reflection, annotations, suppress-warnings

I am currently working on a java project that needs to display the meta information of a java class like the annotations that have been declared for methods, parameters, etc.

I have the following classes

**Employee.java**

```
package labsheet;

public class Employee {

    private String eid = "E001";
    String ename = "Anura";
    public String address = "Batticaloa";
    protected double salary = 60_000.00;

    public String getEid() {
        return eid;
    }
    public void setEid(String eid) {
        this.eid = eid;
    }
    String getEname() {
        return ename;
    }
    void setEname(String ename) {
        this.ename = ename;
    }
    protected String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    protected void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String display(String eid, String ename, String address, double salary){
        System.out.println("Method invoked successfully");
        return eid+" , "+ename+" , "+address+" , "+salary;
    }


}
```

In my main class ***Task3.java*** I am trying to display the annotations that are available in the ***Employee.java***. And hence I intend to display the `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` details for the methods getSalary() and setSalary() using Java Reflection.

I have currently coded the ***Task3.java*** as follows.

**Task3.java**

```
package labsheet;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;

public class Task3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("labsheet.Employee");
            Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();

            for(int m =0; m<methods.length;m++){
                System.out.println("Modifier=> "+ Modifier.toString(methods[m].getModifiers()));
                Annotation [] annotations = methods[m].getAnnotations();
                System.out.println("Annotation count: "+annotations.length);
                for(int o =0; o<annotations.length;o++){
                    System.out.println("Annotation "+(o+1)+": "+annotations[o]);
                }
                System.out.print("|| Return Type=> "+ methods[m].getReturnType());
                System.out.print("|| Method Name=> "+ methods[m].getName());
                Parameter[] parameters = methods[m].getParameters();
                if(parameters.length != 0){
                    System.out.print("|| Method Parameters=> ");
                    for(int u = 0; u<parameters.length;u++){
                        if(u== parameters.length-1){
                            System.out.print(parameters[u].getType().getSimpleName());
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.print(parameters[u].getType().getSimpleName()+" ");
                        }
                    }
                }

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("*******************************");
            executeMethod();
            System.out.println("*******************************");
            executeMethodWithDefault();
        } 

        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

...
//Methods declaration for executeMethod() and executeMethodWithDefault()

}
```

But I am getting an output where it says that there are no annotations for the getSalary() and setSalary() methods as well, whereas I need the `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` annotation details to be displayed here.

**Output**

```
Modifier=> protected
Annotation count: 0
|| Return Type=> class java.lang.String|| Method Name=> getAddress

Modifier=> public
Annotation count: 0
|| Return Type=> class java.lang.String|| Method Name=> display|| Method Parameters=> String String String double

Modifier=> private
Annotation count: 0
|| Return Type=> void|| Method Name=> setSalary|| Method Parameters=> double

Modifier=> 
Annotation count: 0
|| Return Type=> class java.lang.String|| Method Name=> getEname

Modifier=> protected
Annotation count: 0
|| Return Type=> void|| Method Name=> setAddress|| Method Parameters=> String

Modifier=> 
Annotation count: 0
|| Return Type=> void|| Method Name=> setEname|| Method Parameters=> String

Modifier=> private
Annotation count: 0
|| Return Type=> double|| Method Name=> getSalary

Modifier=> public
Annotation count: 0
|| Return Type=> class java.lang.String|| Method Name=> getEid

Modifier=> public
Annotation count: 0
|| Return Type=> void|| Method Name=> setEid|| Method Parameters=> String
```

Any suggestions in this regard will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `java.lang.SuppressWarnings` class:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface SuppressWarnings {
  // code...
}
```

It has `SOURCE` retention policy (see `java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy` class):

```
public enum RetentionPolicy {
    /**
     * Annotations are to be discarded by the compiler.
     */
    SOURCE,
    // code...
}
```

This means that it is impossible to get an information about the annotation in a runtime, as compiler doesn't place it into the class files.